# Panel Drawing zoom in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, panel

I have a Form that contain a panel, and in this panel I draw shapes, like rectangles and circles, I need to zoom into this shapes, I saw couple options but most of them using PictureBox. Should I use Bitmap creating the panel area as a bitmap and change the zooming factor ?? would this help me also further if I want to have Panning and not draw images not into the fit in the panel size.

Here is a snapshot of my code

```
  private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
        int RecScale = 1;
        foreach (CircuitData.ResistorRow resistorRow in ResistorData.Resistor)
        {
            RectangleF rec = new RectangleF((float)(resistorRow.CenterX - resistorRow.Length / 2), (float)(resistorRow.CenterY - resistorRow.Width/ 2), (float)resistorRow.Length, (float)resistorRow.Width);
            float orientation = 360 - (float)resistorRow.Orientation;
            PointF center = new PointF((float)resistorRow.CenterX, (float)resistorRow.CenterY);
            PointF[] points = CreatePolygon(rec, center, orientation);
            if (!Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiX) && !Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiY))
            {
                g.FillEllipse(myBrush, (float)resistorRow.HiX - 5 , (float)resistorRow.HiY - 5, 10, 10);
                g.DrawLine(p, new PointF((float)resistorRow.HiX, (float)resistorRow.HiY), center);
            }
            g.FillPolygon(myBrush, points);
        }
    }
```

Can a sample code be provided. 
Many Thanks

Jp

Comment: If you want to you can scale the Graphics object. But first repair the broken code in your paint event!!! Exchange `Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();` for `Graphics g = e.Graphics;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way to scale the drawing by [scaling the Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);

    // some demo drawing:
    Rectangle rect = panel1.ClientRectangle;
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 4f)) g.DrawLine(pen, 22, 22, 88, 88);

}
```

Here we store the zoom level:

```
float zoom = 1f;
```

Here we set it and update the Panel:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // for zooming between, say 5% - 500%
   // let the value go from 50-50000, and initialize to 100 !
    zoom = trackBar1.Value / 100f;  
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Two example screenshots:

[image][image]

Note how nicely this scales the Pen widths as well. Turning on antialiasing would be a good idea..: `g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;`

Comment: Is it possible to put a scroll bar to view the zoomed content?

Comment: @Abhishek, you got the solution to zoom the picture and getting the scrollbar in the panel, (Scrollbar is to drag and see the rest of the image)

Comment: The easier solution are either to put the panel1 into a panel2 which has autoscroll on. Or to set autoscroll and the minsize for panel1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're drawing from scratch, couldn't you resize you drawing base on zoom factor?

You could multiply your drawing dimensions by your zoom factor. Assuming your zoom factor would be:

- 0.5 for 50 % zoom *(which would reduce the drawing size)*
- 1.0 for 100% *(Real size)*
- 1.5 for 150 % *(bigger size)*, you could calc the width this way:

```
object.Width = originalWidth * zoomFactor;
```

Comment: By saying Object width is the Graphic object g in my code case or each shape i'm drawing.

Comment: Each object. In fact you would need to do that with every object dimension.