# How to zoom picturebox along with graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox, windows

I want to zoom picture box along with graphics.

this will Zoom the only image part not the graphics part.

```
public Image PictureBoxZoom(Image imgP, Size size)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(imgP, Convert.ToInt32(imgP.Width * size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(imgP.Height * size.Height));
    Graphics grap = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    grap.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    return bm;
}

private void zoomSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (zoomSlider.Value > 0 && img != null)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Image = PictureBoxZoom(img, new Size(zoomSlider.Value, zoomSlider.Value));
    }
}
```

the source of image is:

```
img = Image.FromStream(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());
```

Picture is zooming but when we draw the rectangle outside image then it's not zooming along with image.

See image:

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I want to get the current image for zooming with graphics. I dont want to save it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15743/Pan-and-Zoom-Very-Large-Images    this link may help u

Comment: @Dandy Its not working from my case.

Comment: @user1868381 Show us your drawing code

Comment: private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            var g = e.Graphics;

            g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(mouseDownPosition, new Size(mouseMovePosition.X - mouseDownPosition.X, mouseMovePosition.Y - mouseDownPosition.Y)));
            if (isMoving)
            {
                foreach (var circle in Circles)
                {
                    g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(circle.Key, new Size(circle.Value.X - circle.Key.X, circle.Value.Y - circle.Key.Y)));
                }
            }

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (rather) easily by scaling the `e.Graphics` object in the `Paint` event.. See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204274/panel-drawing-zoom-in-c-sharp/32204516?s=2|0.3078#32204516)!

So to work with you code you probably should add this to the Paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Graphics g = e.Graphics;

  g.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);

  // now do your drawing..
  // here just a demo ellipse and a line..
  Rectangle rect = panel1.ClientRectangle;
  g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
  using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 4f)) g.DrawLine(pen, 22, 22, 88, 88);
}
```

To calculate the zoom factor you need to do a little calculation.

Usually you would not create a zoomed Image but leave that job to the PictureBox with a `SizeMode=Zoom`.

Then you could write:

```
float zoom =  1f * pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / pictureBox1.Image.Width;
```

To **center** the image one usually moves the `PictureBox` **inside** a `Panel`. And to allow **scrolling**  one sets the Panel to `Autocroll=true;`

But since you are creating a zoomed Image you should keep track of the current zoom by some other means.

**Note:**

But as you use `PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage` maybe your problem is not with the zooming after all?? If your issue really is the placement, not the size of the drawn graphics you need to do a `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform` to move it to the right spot..