# PictureBox pin, zoom, pan like the Google Map

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a Windows Forms application. Basically I want to use maps features on my picture. I have a picture and I want to pin something on this Pic. But the pins will stay same coordinates when I zoom in, zoom out or pan . Just like a Map.

The main problem is;
Pins are not stay where they are when zoom and pan. That's why I need something like map features.

Comment: You may want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011251/how-to-zoom-picturebox-along-with-graphics/33085958?r=SearchResults&s=1|83.4237#33085958) that shows how to zoom an image and graphics drawn onto i..

Comment: I will check, thank you. @TaW

Answer (score 0):

you can embed Google Maps into your webpage
[this is how to do it](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=Embed%20a%20map%20or%20directions&text=the%20embedded%20map.-,Open%20Google%20Maps.,you%27d%20like%20to%20embed.&text=Click%20Embed%20map.,the%20text%20in%20the%20box.) (its way easier than making one on its own) But I see you are not trying to add a map to a webpage. What use does it have for then? (your picture with a needle)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned it. I am developing an windows forms:( Can I implement it to windows forms?

Comment: i guess so.. you need to create a "Browse View" here is the source of this knowledge 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/embed-google-maps-in-net-desktop-application/#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20embed%20and%20display%20Google%20Maps%20in%20your%20.&text=NET%20application%20you%20just%20need,method%20of%20its%20Browser%20property.

Comment: I think I didn't make it about asking a question. Also I will use my own picture. The application will not be a map application. I just want to use maps features on my own picture and my picture is not a map. Just a floor plan. I will pin some camera icons on picture and will use them as a button. But when I zoom or pan the cameras have to stay same coordinates.

Comment: maybe you can "subordinate" the pin object under the image and then add logic that the image will move with the mouse and in this case follow the pin perfectly (but I don't know if this is possible in Windows Forms, all that I know is that "shapes" have an effect that they drag an object with them)

Comment: This is really though. Things getting mess when zoom in and pan. Pff.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).