# Resizing drawlines on a paint event

Tags: c#, drawing, picturebox, zooming

I've seen few questions about this problem, I tried every solution but none of them worked for my case.
My code is working; this [image](https://i.hizliresim.com/aLO015.png) shows what happens when I click on Draw button.
I need to zoom on that drawing.Is it possible to code something like autocad feature "zoom/extent"?

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
int centerpointx, centerpointy;
private void pictureBoxDraw_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        centerpointx = pictureBoxDraw.Size.Width/2;
        centerpointy = pictureBoxDraw.Size.Height/2;

        myPen.Width = 2;
        if (binary > 0)
        {
            var sizecrestgeo = 40;
            var distancearraycrestgeo = new float[sizecrestgeo];
            var elevationarraycrestgeo = new float[sizecrestgeo];
            for (int i = 0; i < sizecrestgeo; i++)
            {
                distancearraycrestgeo[i] = float.Parse(dataGridViewCrestGeo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                elevationarraycrestgeo[i] = float.Parse(dataGridViewCrestGeo.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())*-1;

            }
            for (int i=0; i < sizecrestgeo-1; i++)
            {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, distancearraycrestgeo[i]+centerpointx, elevationarraycrestgeo[i]+centerpointy, distancearraycrestgeo[i + 1]+centerpointx, elevationarraycrestgeo[i + 1]+centerpointy);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    private void buttonDraw_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Hd > 0.0001)
        {
            binary = 1;
            pictureBoxDraw.Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data to draw, perform analysis first.");
        }

    }

    private void buttoncleardraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binary = 0;
        pictureBoxDraw.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can scale the Graphics object. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204274/panel-drawing-zoom-in-c-sharp/32204516#32204516) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204274/panel-drawing-zoom-in-c-sharp/32204516?s=4|0.8505#32204516) for examples.

Comment: Note that even the pens' width are scaled, so you may want to use smaller than 1px in your Paint. They will still be drawn with 1px minimum.

Comment: @TaW helpful examples and warning, thank you. [img1](https://i.hizliresim.com/V0q6oV.png) [img2](https://i.hizliresim.com/1LQDmp.png) Actually this is not what I exactly want. I don't want user to control this, I should somehow center the drawing..

Comment: To keep a point centered you will add a TranslateTransform. Do plan ahead for possible scrolling!

Comment: @TaW can you give me also an example for that? I have no idea about TranslateTransform thing..

Answer (score 1):

This is not so hard, provided you know all the puzzle pieces.

Let's start with the obvious one:

- You can scale the `Graphics` object to create **zoomed** graphics with `ScaleTransform`.

As I mentioned, this will include the widths of pens, font sizes and also any images you draw (though not the hatches of a `HatchBrush`).

You also asked about keeping the drawing 'centered'. This is a non-obvious concept: Just what is the **center** of your drawing surface??

When zooming (just like rotating) you always need to know the **center point** of the zoom (or the rotation.) By default this is the origin `(0,0)`. I chose the center of the `Panel`. You may want to pick some other point..

Once you do you can move the origin of the graphics viewport to this point with `TranslateTransform`.

Once you have achieved all this you almost certainly will want to allow **scrolling**.

To do so you have two options:

- You can keep `AutoScroll = false` and **nest** the canvas control inside **another** control, usually a `Panel`, which has `AutoScroll = true`; next make the canvas control big enough to always hold your drawing and you're done.
- Or you can turn on `AutoScroll`  for the  canvas control and also set a large enough `AutoScrollMinSize`. If you then add the current scrolling position to the translation you are also done. Let's see this solution in action:

[image]

This is the code in the `Paint` event:

```
Size sz = panel3.ClientSize;
Point center = new Point(sz.Width / 2, sz.Height / 2);
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

// center point for testing only!
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Orange, center.X - 3, center.Y - 3, 6, 6);

// you determine the value of the zooming!
float zoom = (trackBar1.Value+1) / 3f;

// move the scrolled center to the origon
g.TranslateTransform(center.X + panel3.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
                        center.Y + panel3.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
// scale the graphics
g.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);

// draw some stuff..
using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 0.1f))
for (int i = -100; i < 100; i+= 10)
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Yellow, i-22,i-22,44,44);
```

A few notes:

- I draw an orange circle in the center to show this point is **invariant**.
- My coordinates go from the negative to the positive so you can see that this works nicely.
- I draw with a tiny pen width; so the width of the drawing only changes once the resulting pen goes over 1 pixel. Anything draw will always be draw with 1 pxiel width, though.
- I first translate and then scale so I don't have to calculate scaled poitions.
- The only line in the `TrackBar`'s `Scroll` event is to trigger the `Paint` event: `panel3.Invalidate();`

The only settings needed for the `Panel` are

```
 panel3.AutoScroll = true;
 panel3.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(500, 500);  // use the size you want to allow!
```

However to avoid **flicker** it is highly recommended to use a `DoubleBuffered` control, maybe a `Panel` subclass like this:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{
    public DrawPanel()      { DoubleBuffered = true;  }
}
```

---

**Update:** Instead of a `Panel`, which is a `Container` control and not really meant to draw onto you can use a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

Answer (score 0):

[Graphics.ScaleTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx) is how you can zoom.  Try using something like this inside your paint event handler:

```
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(2.0F, 2.0F);
```