# C# Resize a drawing in a graphics component

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I have drawn something in a graphics component, that is shown on a picturebox. Is there a way to resize it?
If I use

```
Graphics grapics;
grapics = panel1.CreateGraphics();
//Drawing
grapics.ScaleTransform(5,5);
//still the same size, but the things i will draw from this moment are 5 times bigger
```

it will only resize the drawings, I will draw from this moment on.

Comment: Yup, that's how it is. Not a problem really because you __need to be able__ to draw __everything__ in your Paint event anyway __whenever__ you or the system calls it. - If you are not using it your code is wrong and your drawing will not persist a min/maximize sequence..

Comment: It quite better if you post the code you're using and possibly explain what a *graphics component* is in this context.

Comment: Sorry my friend but you will have to rewrite/rethink your code! - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Comment: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event. - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079331/resizing-drawlines-on-a-paint-event/44088560#44088560)